# How to pass argument to JavaScript function from user?

Tags: javascript

I have problem with recursion function. 
Lets say we have Fibbonaci algorithm:

```
function fib(n){
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n==1){
        return 1;
    }
    else 
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

How shall i handle this function with user interface ? I want to be able to pass argument from user. Typicaly, I work this out like the function below, but, in this case, we have recursion function...

```
<input type="text" id="n">
<button id="button1">Compute Fib</button>

var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.addEventListener("click", Fib, false);


function Fib(){
    var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
    n = parseInt(n);
    if(n == 0){
        return 0;
    } else if(n == 1){
       return 1;
    } else {
        n = n - 1;
        return n*Fib(); // ???
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read n out from fib function, and then use your above function with n with your first function?

Comment: do you want to see the sequence of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a separate function call the recursive function.

```
<input type="text" id="n">
<button id="button1">Compute Fib</button>

var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
button1.addEventListener("click", onClickComputeFib, false);


function onClickComputeFib(){
    var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
    n = parseInt(n);
    fib(n);
}

function fib(n){
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    } else if(n==1){
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `Fib` to accept a parameter for `n` instead of grabbing it from inside the function itself.

```
button1.addEventListener("click", function() { Fib(document.getElementById('n').value); }, false);

function Fib(n) {
    ...
    return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2); // this is your ??? line
```

Answer (score -1):

I think problem of you is you get value n from Fib, so everyone call Fib function then n always equals n origin.

You trying change it like:

```
function Fib(){
var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
n = parseInt(n);
return fib_cal(n);
}

function fib_cal(n){
if(n==0){
return 0;
}
else if(n==1){
return 1;
}
else 
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `onclick` event of `button`

```
<input type="text" id="n">
<button id="button1" onclick="compute()">Compute Fib</button>


function compute(){
var n = document.getElementById("n").value;
n = parseInt(n);
calculateFib(n);
}
function calculateFib(n){
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    } else if(n==1){
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With this line of code `n*Fib(n-1)` u are calculating the factorial value of a number. Please correct it to `fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`.
Check this link [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/e4jm7mhf/) to see a simple working example.

hope it useful!

Comment: The OP doesn't have the line of code you mentioned, `n*Fib(n-1)`. He does have `n*Fib()`, however, that is in the non-working example he gives, which he clearly marks as being his point of confusion. If you look at his first function, you will see the exact line you recommended using.